# Elasticsearch - aggregation of unique counts

Tags: elasticsearch, subquery, aggregation

I have an Elasticsearch database of books:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Animal Farm"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Brave New World"
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Nineteen Eighty-Four"
},
{
  "id": 4,
  "name": "Animal Farm"
},
{
  "id": 5,
  "name": "We"
}
```

As you can see, the books with `id` of `1` and `4` have the conflict book name "Animal Farm". However, they are different books. One is by George Orwell, and another one is literally about farm animals.

I want to know how often do the book names conflict. For the example above, the expected results are:

```
{
  "conflicts": [
    {
      "num_of_books": 2,
      "count": "1"
    },
    {
      "num_of_books": 1,
      "count": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

The entry with `num_of_books` of `2` is the conflict of "Animal Farm", and it happened once (therefore the `count` is `1`). The other 3 books has all different names, so they appears in the entry with `num_of_books` of `1` and `count` of `3`. I *don't* need the names of the books. Only the counts matter.

I know SQL has "subquery" to do this:

```
SELECT num_of_books, COUNT(*) AS _count
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_of_books
  FROM books
  GROUP BY name
)
GROUP BY num_of_books;
```

I read the articles of [Nested Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) and [Sub-Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/blog/intro-to-aggregations-pt-2-sub-aggregations), but failed to see the possibility to achieve my goal.

Any comment will help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Running aggregations on aggregations is not yet possible in ES, as far as I know. I know of a few outstanding issues on allowing to apply additional logic on the results of bucket aggregations, but they are still being discussed and debated.

In your case, you can get away with the inner SQL query by using a `terms` aggregation in order to get the name of all conflicting books by using `min_doc_count: 2`.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "books": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "name",
                "min_doc_count": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can parse the buckets on the client side and re-bucket them into new `num_of_books` buckets depending on their count. For instance, using the head plugin you can add the following code in the Transform section

```
var num_of_books = {};
root.aggregations.books.buckets.forEach(function(b) {
    num_of_books[b.doc_count] = (num_of_books[b.doc_count] || 0) + 1;
});
return num_of_books;
```

`num_of_books` would then contain something like this:

```
{
    "2": 1,
    "1": 3
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the amount of data wouldn't allow me to do the outer aggregation on the client side. Is there any way to do all the calculation on the server? Like using scripted fields?

Comment: Just for starters, have you tried what I'm suggesting just to see what the performance yields? With the head plugin, you can check how it works in less than a minute.

Comment: Yes, I tried your solution, and it takes too long for my customers to wait for it. I need the calculation be done in less than 10 seconds.

Comment: Is there any way you can pre-compute the inner aggregation and store it in another index on which you'd run the outer aggregation? How often does your book index change?

Comment: Can I store the results of the inner aggregation in some temporary index without making the client download the results (i.e. all the operations are done on the server side)?

Comment: May I ask how many documents you have and the cardinality of your inner aggregation (i.e. how many book name terms)?

Comment: There are 849164 documents, and the cardinality of the inner aggregation is 845211.

Comment: with `min_doc_count: 2` you get 845211 terms in the inner aggregation? that would mean most books have conflicting names? Is that right?

Comment: What do you get is you run this `SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_of_books FROM books GROUP BY name HAVING num_of_books > 1`